# Google gmail notifier css

Tags: css, gmail

When sending message or discard an email, at the top there  will be a yellow box with message "Your message has been discarded. Undo discard". I want exactly the same Google css style.
Any example and advise is welcome. Thank you

Please refer image below with the links

[Print screen](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B8pQuTUbR9h8cWFZWEZLNXA4ZmM/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: If you want to copy the CSS style, you can easily inspect it via dev console in chrome and grab CSS from there. (right click on the message and inspect element). It should be <div class="vh">, at least for me. If I understood correctly.

Answer (score 4):

Another example (straight from gmail css)

**http://jsfiddle.net/VVbZZ/1/**

css:

```
.notification-container {
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 8;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.notification-message {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    visibility: visible;
    font-size: 80%;
    padding: 6px 10px;
    background-color: #f9edbe;
    border: 1px solid #f0c36d;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

html:

```
<div class="notification-container">
    <div class="notification-message"> 
       <span>Loading... <a href="damn.com">Click to learn more</a></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**result:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use the below css:

```
.verticalBox {
  margin: 0 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 8px;
  z-index: 990;
  border-color: #f0c36d;
  background-color: #f9edbe;
  padding: 0 10px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 2px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  background: #f9edbe;
  border-color: #f9edbe;
  color: #222;
  padding: 0 7px;
  font-size: 80%;
  font-weight: bold; 
  text-align: center;
}
```

And use the following HTML:

```
<div class="verticalBox">This is testing</div>
```

This is similar to gmail message.

**result:**

[image]

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8RkHq/)